# JQuery stores previous defined variable

Tags: jquery

I have a list of comments in my app. User needs to show/hide them in him/her control panel by clicking an icon.

You can see some comments here :

```
<div><a  href="" class="hideComment" title="show/hide" data-commnetid="74" data-approved="0" >Show</a></div>

<div><a  href="" class="hideComment" title="show/hide" data-commnetid="71" data-approved="0" >show</a></div>

<div><a  href="" class="hideComment" title="show/hide" data-commnetid="70" data-approved="1" >hide</a></div>
```

**approved == 0** is means that your comment is hide, you can show it, **approved == 1** is reverse.

this is jquery code that comes after above comments list :

```
$(function () {
   $(".hideComment").click(function () {

     var url = "<?php echo \Cake\Routing\Router::url(array('controller' => 'videos', 'action' => 'hideshowcomment')) ?>";
     var commentID = $(this).attr('data-commnetid');
     var approved = $(this).attr('data-approved');
     alert(approved);
     if(approved == 1){
         $( this ).html('show');
         $('.hideComment').attr('data-approved',0);
     }else if (approved == 0) {
         $( this ).html('hide');
         $('.hideComment').attr('data-approved',1);
     }
     $.ajax({
         dataType: 'json',
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: {id : commentID},
         success: function (data) {
             //alert('success');
         }
     });  
     return false;
  });
});
```

first click on an item works very well. However, if I click another item it shows wrong message.

***var approved*** stores previous **data-approved**. The rest of code work, It sends an ajax request to the *hideshowcomment* action and so on.

Comment: is there anywhere in your code you are using `data('approved')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, only this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the current element's value, not all the `hideComment` elements

```
$(this).attr('data-approved', 1);
```

When you set `$('.hideComment').attr('data-approved',0);` you are changing the attribute value of all `hideComment` elements in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var approved = $(this).data("approved")
```

instead of the

```
 var approved = $(this).attr('data-approved');
```

And the same  for the commentID attribute.

Comment: I added your code and just replaced attr with data and it works in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qag9eu4r/